# Problems while parsing a CSV file in Java

Tags: java, parsing, csv, opencsv

In this code the aim is to parse a CSV file and to map its data to a bean object.

```
ColumnPositionMappingStrategy strat = new ColumnPositionMappingStrategy();
strat.setType(Country.class);
String[] columns = new String[] {"countryName", "capital"};
strat.setColumnMapping(columns);

CsvToBean csv = new CsvToBean();

String csvFilename = "C:/Users/user/Desktop/sample.csv";
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(csvFilename));
```

The columns in the file have a header and sometimes additional information below the raw data (like a number or a word in a String or a Integer cell).

I asked how to ignore this additional information in a prior question, and got this code as an answer :

```
List<Country> list = new ArrayList<Country>();
String [] row = csvReader.readNext(); //skip header
    if(row == null) throw new RuntimeException("File is empty");
    row = csvReader.readNext();
    String [] nextRow = csvReader.readNext();
    while(row != null) {
       if(nextRow == null) break; //check what 'row' is last
       if("Total:".equalsIgnoreCase(row[1])) break; //check column for special strings

       list.add(csv.processLine(strat, row)); <----

       row = nextRow;
       nextRow = csvReader.readNext();
```

As I tried to implement this code, i got two errors at the line marked by an arrow.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation
>   problems:
>
> The method add(Country) in the type List is not
>   applicable for the arguments (Object)
>
> The method processLine(MappingStrategy, String[]) from the type CsvToBean is not visible

Does anybody know how to solve this issues? I'm fairly new to Java.

Thank you very much.

Comment: What does `processLine` return?

Comment: the processLine methods needs to return a Country. If the line returns a String of country information, create countries: add(new Country(processLine(strat, row));

Comment: Your CSVToBean needs to get the argument. You'll want to create: CsvToBean<Country> csv = new CsvToBean<>(). That way the bean knows the generic return type.

Comment: Thank you it solved the first problem! But the second one persists

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The method processLine(MappingStrategy, String[]) from the type
>   CsvToBean is not visible

means this method must be accesible(possible cause; it is private, protected or friendly), so use public

> The method add(Country) in the type List is not applicable for the
>   arguments (Object)

and must return type country, method signature must be something like;

```
public Country processLine(ColumnPositionMappingStrategy strat, String [] row)
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution should be downcast the response from processLine to Country, like this:

list.add(csv.processLine(strat, row));
to
list.add((Country) csv.processLine(strat, row));

But your second question, about method visibility makes clear that you are not using the public API of the library.
Please read the documentation and examples of the library, to know how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [CSVToBeanFilter](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/bean/CsvToBeanFilter.html) I pointed out in [your previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35695348/only-partialially-parse-a-csv-file-with-opencsv) and it should solve your problem.